# jQuery .focus() after .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, show, synchronous

I have the following code that hides one text box and shows another. When the next one shows, I need the cursor to be on it, so I call `.focus()` on it. However, even though I have the call to `.focus()` as the second parameter, it still isn't focusing. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dummy-password-input').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show(0, function() {
            $(this).focus();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: could have been better if you give us a fiddle to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble everybody. It turns out that after messing with it some more, my DOM traversal wasn't quite right. I removed the divs I had around the input boxes and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That behavoiur occurs, becaus $(this) refers to the just hidden input field change your code like:

```
        $(this).next().show(0, function() {
            $(this).next().focus();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dummy-password-input').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show().focus();
    });
});
```

EDIT:

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/hbyA7/)